# How to remove console in masm assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm new to assembly and every program I run opens up a console (like cmd) in the background. Is there anyway to fix this as it is annoying?'

I'm using masm assembly, though Im not sure what that means.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data

boxcap db "A simple box", 0
message db "<3 Madi",0
abort db "ABORT",0



.code
start: 
    invoke MessageBox,
                        NULL,
                        addr message,
                        addr boxcap,
                        MB_ICONERROR OR MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE

    .IF eax==IDABORT
        invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr abort, addr abort, MB_OK
    .ELSEIF eax==IDRETRY
        invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr abort, addr abort, MB_OK 
    .ELSEIF eax == IDCANCEL

    .ENDIF

    invoke ExitProcess,NULL

end start
```

That is the code, sorry for not posting earlier.

Comment: If you don't show us what you're doing, it's impossible to see what might be going wrong. We can't debug what we can't see, and you've not given any information. (You've basically said "Doctor, I have a pain somewhere. My species is human. What's wrong, and how do I make it stop?". Ask your own doctor that question, and see if you get a diagnosis and treatment based on that vague explanation of the problem. I'd be willing to bet your doctor won't be willing to give you either without a much greater amount of information.) And "masm" is "Microsoft Assembler" (based on the .asm extension).

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` option to the linker. If you're linking with the ML command add `/link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` to the end of your command line.

Using the `/SUBSYSTEM` option changes how the Microsoft linker chooses the default entry point if you don't use the `/ENTRY` option. The [rules for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) are a bit complicated, but if you were using `mainCRTStartup` before you may need to change that to `WinMainCRTStartup`.

Oh, and MASM stands for Macro Assembler, it's full name is Microsoft Macro Assembler. There used to be an ASM assembler that didn't support macros.

Comment: Ok, my compile script is a batch file that is set as :

\masm32\bin\ml /c /Zd /coff Msgbox.asm

\masm32\bin\Link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE Msgbox.obj

What should I change?

Sorry, I'm new to assembly.

Thank you for your answer regardless of if you reply now.

Comment: Change `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` to `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` in your batch file.

Comment: Thank you Ross! Sorry I didn't see it earlier. It now works perfectly.